# In Oracle Apex, how to concatenante two columns in classic report?

Tags: oracle-apex

In oracle Apex, need to concanetate two columns in classic report. These columns are type of Link and Donwload BLOB. Both of them are displayed with fa-edit and fa-download icon respectively.

Of course, I know how to concatenate two columns in sql query in this case i cant concanetate these columns.

Is there a way to concatenate these columns in oracle apex page designer?

Already tried thorugh sql query but i didn't get what wanted.

Comment: The buttons are generally a display property of the column itself, linked to the content of the columns as a whole. I don't believe you can set the property to display multiple buttons based on partial column values. Why is this important?

Comment: i have id column as link (link text: <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>) and file_blob column as download BLOB (download text: <span class="fa fa-download"></span>).
As a task i need to concanetate these two columns if it is possible?
So, in one column need to display these two icons with their funcionalities?
I wonder is that even possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The functionality - the links behind the visible buttons - is based on the column content (i.e. the actual ID value and the BLOB content), so you can't really concatenate them.

Comment: Not knowing of your code but, just an idea, can't you just extract the class name from download text and concatenate it with your link text and then try? for example, your merged link will be `<span class="fa fa-edit fa fa-download"></span>` ?